# WordPress AJAX request returns 0

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

TL;DR: **Not Dupe** - Code first, scroll to bottom for problem.

Here is [the link to the demo that I currently have](http://carotape.bigwolfdesigns.com/product-selector/).

In `functions.php` I localize my script first:

```
function ajaxurl(){
    wp_enqueue_script( 'product-selector', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/ajax.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
    wp_localize_script( 'product-selector', 'MyAjax', array(
    // URL to wp-admin/admin-ajax.php to process the request
        'ajaxurl'          => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
        // generate a nonce with a unique ID "myajax-post-comment-nonce"
        // so that you can check it later when an AJAX request is sent
        //'postCommentNonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'myajax-post-comment-nonce' ),
        )
    );
}
add_action('wp_head', 'ajaxurl');
```

And then for the script my ajax calls on I have:

```
function ajax_callback() {
    global $wpdb; // this is how you get access to the database
    // Declare our variable.
    $cat = $_POST['cat'];
    // Q the DB
    $query = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare(
        "
            SELECT meta_value 
            FROM $wpdb->postmeta
            WHERE post_category=%s
        ", $cat
        ) );
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    wp_send_json( json_encode( $query ) );
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax-callback', 'ajax_callback' );
```

And finally for ajax.js I have:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var back_end_script_url = MyAjax.ajaxurl;
   $(function() {
   var category_callback = function(data) {
       console.log(data);
       var adhesion_select = $('#adhesion');
       var substrate_select = $('#substrate');
       substrate_select.find('option').remove();
       adhesion_select.find('option').remove();
       for (var k in data) {
           var option = $('<option />').val(k).html(data[k]);
           adhesion_select.append(option);
       }
   };
   var adhesion_callback = function(data) {
       console.log(data);
       var substrate_select = $('#substrate');
       substrate_select.find('option').remove();
       for (var k in data) {
           var option = $('<option />').val(k).html(data[k]);

           substrate_select.append(option);
       }
   };
   var category_change = function() {
       console.log('Category Changed');
       var category = $(this).find(":selected").val();
       var params = {
           action: 'ajax-callback',
           cat: category
       };
       console.log(params);
       $.post(back_end_script_url, params, category_callback);
   };
   var adhesion_change = function() {
       console.log('Adhesion Changed');
       var adhesion = $(this).find(":selected").val();
       var category = $('#cat').find(":selected").val();
       var params = {
           action: 'ajax-callback',
           cat: category,
           adhesion: adhesion
       };
       console.log(params);
           $.post(back_end_script_url, params, adhesion_callback);
       };
       $('#cat').on('change', category_change);
       $('#adhesion').on('change', adhesion_change);
   });
});
```

So my problem is, if you look at the demo, the ajax only returns the number 0, not the data from the db.

I have read every related question on this problem on stack and wordpress exchanges, and tried all of them out, and my result is always the same.

I hired out the JS code, but the guy swears its on my end. I'm not sure if that's true or not, because I can't find any problem in my code.

Thanks for your help, Stack!

Comment: The php needs work as well, but my problem was the `action: ajax-callback`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are missing the "action" attribute in the params you are sending on the ajax call.

Your params object should be:

```
var params = {
  action: "ajax-call",
  cat: category
};
```

Hope this helps,

Regards,

Marcelo

Comment: Still returning a single 0. I feel like it is a simple thing I'm overlooking, though.

Comment: Sorry, i wrote the wrong "action" in my answer above. It should be "ajax-callback". Did you try with that one too? Also, did you debug the code and you are sure it is getting to your function "ajax-callback"?

Comment: It is getting to my function. That part works correctly. Now the function isn't returning any results - just `[]`, leaving my code to look like  : `<option>[</option><option>]</option>`

Comment: What about using this workaround, instead of the "correct way":
> echo json_encode($query); die();
Instead of
> header('Content-Type: application/json');
> wp_send_json( json_encode( $query ) );

Comment: Same result: `[]` is all that's returned. The problem must be with my db query, I'd guess.

Comment: I was not checking the query. As you say, you are right. THat query is not ok. You are asking for the field "post_category" and that is not a field from that DB. In postmeta, the fields you have are "meta_key" and "meta_value". So, i guess your query should say "WHERE meta_key = 'post_vategory' and meta_value=%s".

Comment: Well I'm trying to draw out the post meta key values - custom field values - from posts with the selected category, then list those custom field values into a select box. 

I can't even get it to return post titles for the given category.

If I build out a dummy json array, it works (sort of - it displays every character in its own option box), but I can't get it to work with a db query.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60471/discussion-between-mindastic-and-remy-sheppard).