# wp-admin ajax request returns 0

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

wp-admin ajax request keeps giving 0 as response no matter what I tried. I read many solutions, articles and answers I found in Google ([including this in SOF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25626294/wordpress-ajax-request-returns-0)) and I believe that my codes are proper.

My ajax call is as follows:

```
$.ajax( {
    url : base_url
        + "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
    type : 'POST',
    cache : false,
    dataType : "json",
    data: {action: "get_next_post_with_ajax"},
    success: function(response){
       // functions I'll work on success.. 
    }
});
```

...and my ajax handler action is like this:

```
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_get_next_post_with_ajax", "get_next_post_with_ajax");

function get_next_post_with_ajax($args) {
    echo "test";
    die();
}
```

Thanks for your help by now.

Comment: Have you tried `exit;` instead of `die();` ?  I have that at the end of my ajax methods.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes I tried but nothing changed. Actually many blogs suggest die(), but I tried all of them.

Comment: FWIW I also have another action in my code without the nopriv: `add_action("wp_ajax_get_next_post_with_ajax", "get_next_post_with_ajax");`

Comment: Thanks, this saved my day, I'll upvote if you write as an answer.
Meanwhile I was thinking that, that hook is only for admin purpose.

Comment: Awesome.  Glad I could help!  An answer has been added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `add_action("wp_ajax_get_next_post_with_ajax", "get_next_post_with_ajax");` for ajax calls occurring from authenticated users.